# Java - session sharing between JSP Servlet app war to Spring 4 based Angular2 Rest war

Tags: spring, angular, rest, servlets, websphere

I have found many posts and link on internet, however nothing seems to work. The application is deployed on websphere 9.0. JDK8 Spring 4.3.9

I am unable to share session attributes between two war applications(as checked session id remains same). We have used

(a) `IBMApplicationSession` instead of `HttpSession`  and

(b) extension to application deployment descriptor . None of the two seems to work.

I have two wars deployed inside an EAR application on IBM WebSphere.  One of the war is a simple old style JSP servlet based application, no spring nothing.

From this war we are forwarding request to `index.html` page of another war application. The second application is an Angular2 Spring 4 based application. The `index.htm` gets generated when we run ‘ng build’ on the angular application. Along with index page loading we are calling a spring MVC Rest controller. We are trying to access an attribute set in application A servlet in the Rest controller. But the session attributes are not there on other side.

I am simply using 
`httpSession.setAttribute("key", "value");` in the Servlet class
then I am doing

```
getServletContext().getContext(anotherContext).getRequestDispatcher(/index.html")
```

In another application, there are couple of HandleInterceptors and then a Spring MVC annotated RestController is being called on the load of index.html using app.routing.ts

Inside RestController - I am trying to get back the attributes using

```
httpRequest.getAttribute("key")
httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("key")
```

To note that the method is a POST Spring RestContoller and `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` and `HttpSession` are added as method arguments.

I have added `HttpSeessionListener` to the spring project to track session creation and destruction. Using this I am able to monitor that no new session is being created or destroyed during the time request is being forwarded and it is received in Spring MVC annotated Rest Controller.

Thanks in advance for your inputs on this..

Comment: You mentioned IBMSession but not packaging your web modules in the same BLA.  That seems to be a requirement for sharing across web modules. 

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=tpersshardate

Comment: thanks for to the point comment - one of the application is practically shut for any sort of extension like moving it classes to a separate JAR. So we would not be able to package the common classes separately external to both the applications (from what I have understood of BLA)                               How about option 2 - I added the extension attribute to share session data, but that is also not working.. Do we have any other option like creating a singleton class with session attribute map and then use this to share the user ID. first app has login screen user would get in.

Comment: You could try to use the DistributeMap feature instead of trying to share the HTTPSession.

Comment: I 'll use the below link to share data between two different contexts (wars) within One BLA EAR application hosted on websphere. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023734&aid=1